Avoiding overlap in frequency and document frequency count in Quanteda
Below is a dummy corpus of 4 documents.
The dictionary was developed to identify the frequency of words or phrases in the corpus, as well as the number of documents a word or phrases occurs in.
The world 'Australians' occurs in two dictionary keys (peep, indig). Key content is intended to be mutually exclusive.
Similarly 'Australia' (oz and Australia Post), foreign (foreign and multinat) and farm/farmers (dairy and farmers) occur in two dictionary keys each,
but are intended to be counted once, according to the dictionary.
The expected overall frequency count is (extracted from the 'pattern" column of the kwic table) and reported as x2 below. Note the word industry appears but is not allocated to industry because it is define din the indig key.
Dairy is the most frequency occuring key, occuring in three documents. This can calculated from unique rows in the kwic table 'doc names' column for each key.
I have three questions:

are there any problems/issues that could affect output accuracy using this approach?
is there a better/more parsimonius approach to achieve what I am trying to do?
what would be the best way to extract the equivalent of tetxstat frequency count data from the kwic table?

        library (quanteda)
        library(quanteda.textstats)

        txt <- c(doc1 = "A significant percent of all farms in Australia, are dairy. 
         Although there are a lot of dairy farms in this country, 
         it is not the biggest farm industry. The life of a farmer is not easy, a dairy 
        farmer has to be an early riser. ",
         doc2 = "Australian people like milk so a healthy dairy industry is important in 
         our country",
         doc3 = "Dairy and sheep farms developed at the expense of Indigenous 
         Australians. Further many companies  are now foreign-owned",
         doc4 = "Some farmers are lucky to receive a service from Australia Post. Mail is 
         sent to many foreign countries and received more quickly than 
         delivered in some locations in Australia.")



         x <- x %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farmers"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farms"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farm"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farming"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy industry"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("indigenous australians"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("australia post"), concatenator = " ") %>%
         tokens_compound(phrase("dairy farmer"), concatenator = " ")
              x

         dict <- dictionary(list(multinat = c("offshore petroleum companies", "foreign- 
         owned", "foreign owned", "foreign companies", "multinational", "multinational 
         oil companies", "multinationals", "transnational"),
         dairy = c("dairy farmers", "dairy farms","dairy farm","dairy farming","dairy 
         industry", "dairy farmer","dairy", "milk"),
         auspost = "australia post",
         oz = c("australia", "this country", "our country"),
         farmers = c("farmers", "farmer", "farm", "farms"),
         foreign = c("foreign", "foreigner", "foreigners"), 
         business =c("small business", "business", "businesses", "company", "companies"),
         indig = c("aboriginal", "aboriginals", "indigenous australians", "torres 
         strait"),
         peep = c("australians", "people of australia", "australian people", "people of 
         this nation", "people of this country"),
         industry = c("industry", "industries")))

        kwicdict <- kwic(x, pattern = dict, window = 4)
        write.csv (kwicdict, "D:/Output/TEST.csv")

       DF <- read.csv("D://Output/TEST.csv",header=T)

       ## obtaining frequency count of KWIC table 'pattern ' values
       > x2 <- DF[,8]
       > 
       > table (x2)
       x2
       auspost business    dairy  farmers  foreign    indig industry multinat  oz  peep    
          1        1        6        5        1        1        1        1     5    2 


I don't think that kwic() is what you want here. tokens_lookup() lets you specify that the nested scope should be mutually exclusive across keys, not just within keys. Observe the difference below. (And note the use of wildcarding for dairy key.)
library(quanteda)
#> Package version: 4.1.0
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 71.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library(quanteda.textstats)

txt <- c(doc1 = "A significant percent of all farms in Australia, are dairy. 
         Although there are a lot of dairy farms in this country, 
         it is not the biggest farm industry. The life of a farmer is not easy, a dairy 
        farmer has to be an early riser. ",
         doc2 = "Australian people like milk so a healthy dairy industry is important in 
         our country",
         doc3 = "Dairy and sheep farms developed at the expense of Indigenous 
         Australians. Further many companies  are now foreign-owned",
         doc4 = "Some farmers are lucky to receive a service from Australia Post. Mail is 
         sent to many foreign countries and received more quickly than 
         delivered in some locations in Australia.")

dict <- dictionary(list(multinat = c("offshore petroleum companies", "foreign-owned", 
                                     "foreign owned", "foreign companies", "multinational", 
                                     "multinational oil companies", "multinationals", "transnational"),
                        dairy = c("dairy farm*", "dairy industry", "dairy", "milk"),
                        auspost = "australia post",
                        oz = c("australia", "this country", "our country"),
                        farmers = c("farmers", "farmer", "farm", "farms"),
                        foreign = c("foreign", "foreigner", "foreigners"), 
                        business =c("small business", "business", "businesses", "company", "companies"),
                        indig = c("aboriginal", "aboriginals", "indigenous australians", "torres strait"),
                        peep = c("australians", "people of australia", "australian people", 
                                 "people of this nation", "people of this country"),
                        industry = c("industry", "industries")))

x <- tokens(txt)

# with overlap
tokens_lookup(x, dict) |>
    dfm()
#> Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 10 features (55.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>       features
#> docs   multinat dairy auspost oz farmers foreign business indig peep industry
#>   doc1        0     3       0  2       5       0        0     0    0        1
#>   doc2        0     2       0  1       0       0        0     0    1        1
#>   doc3        1     1       0  0       1       0        1     1    1        0
#>   doc4        0     0       1  2       1       1        0     0    0        0

# without overlap
tokens_lookup(x, dict, nested_scope = "dictionary") |>
    dfm()
#> Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 10 features (60.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>       features
#> docs   multinat dairy auspost oz farmers foreign business indig peep industry
#>   doc1        0     3       0  2       3       0        0     0    0        1
#>   doc2        0     2       0  1       0       0        0     0    1        0
#>   doc3        1     1       0  0       1       0        1     1    0        0
#>   doc4        0     0       1  1       1       1        0     0    0        0

Created on 2024-10-06 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks Ken, much appreciated. This looks like it will do the job. I compared KWIC output to what the dictionary picked up and out of 42 keys,
there were initially 11 instances where totals differed. Use of the wild key reduced this to 3 instances. I'll have to manually try to work out the discrepancies
